# Is optimization over Borel $\sigma$-algebra attainable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, optimization, supremum-and-infimum, borel-sets

Let $f : \mathcal{B}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a set function where the domain $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, i.e., a collection of all Borel sets.

Is there a source showing $\sup \{ f(B) \ : \ B \in \mathcal{B} \}$ attainable for some $f$? I guess I am looking at a set version of the Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: First of all max may not even exist. Did you mean sup? Also you have to assume something about $f$. Arbitrary functions don't have to attain their sup. Also note that in the question it is irrelevant that $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, since you don't seem to use that property anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have some condition on $f$. For example, if you denote $|S|$ the cardinality of a set $S$, suppose $f: \mathcal{B} \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by  $$f(B) = \begin{cases} 0 & |B| = \infty\\ \frac{|B|}{|B| + 1} & |B| < \infty
\end{cases}.$$ Then $\sup_{B \in \mathcal{B}} f(B) = 1$ is not attained.